# AngularJS Form Validation for select and radios

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have the 2 following form controls and need to know how to validate them with AngularJS.
The State MUST have a value other than blank.

If there is  more than one radio button, there MUST be one selected.

How would I accomplish this in AngularJS?

```
<table class="t_100">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select ng-model="selectedCES" name="state_select" id="state_select_{{PID}}" style="float:left;"
                        ng-options="item as StatesArray[item.CES] for item in CEIC | orderBy: 'CES'"
                        ng-change="stateSelected(this)">
                    <option value="">Please select a State</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in CEIC" class="CEIC" ng-show="selectedCES.CES==item.CES" id="CEIC_{{PID}}_{{item.CES}}">
            <td style="text-align: center;" class="CTC" ng-repeat="item2 in item.CTC" id="CEIT_{{item2.CETID}}" width="{{(1/item.CTC.length)*100|number:0}}%">
                <input type="radio" ng-if="(item.CTC.length>1)" class="lt_" id="lt_{{PID}}_{{item2.CETID}}" name="lt_{{PID}}" value="{{item2.CETID}}" ng-click="stateSelected(this)">
                <input type="hidden" ng-if="(item.CTC.length<2)" class="lt_" id="lt_{{PID}}_{{item2.CETID}}" name="lt_{{PID}}" value="{{item2.CETID}}">
                <label ng-show="(item.CTC.length>1)" class="lt_{{PID}}_{{item2.CETID}}" for="lt_{{PID}}_{{item2.CETID}}" id="lbl_lt_{{PID}}_{{item2.CETID}}">{{item2.LT}}<br />HR: {{item2.HR}}</label>
                <input type="hidden" class="hr_" value="{{item2.HR}}" id="hr_{{PID}}_{{item2.CETID}}" name="hr_{{PID}}_{{item2.CETID}}">
                <input type="hidden" class="un_" value="{{item2.UN}}" id="un_{{PID}}_{{item2.CETID}}" name="un_{{PID}}_{{item2.CETID}}">
                <input type="hidden" class="pr_" value="{{item2.PR}}" id="pr_{{PID}}_{{item2.CETID}}" name="pr_{{PID}}_{{item2.CETID}}" ng-model="itemPR">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Form tag looks like this:

```
<form id="ce_info" ng-submit="send()" ng-show="selectedCEState !=''">
```

Here is stateSelected handler and send handler:

```
// stateSelected handler
$scope.stateSelected = function () {
    var hasOnlyOne = ($scope.selectedCES.CETC.length == 1);
    var item2 = this.item2;
    if($scope.no_ce) {
        $scope.CEI.Declined = 1;
    } else {
        if(item2 == undefined) {
            item2 = $scope.selectedCES.CETC[0];
            $scope.CEI.CES = $scope.selectedCES.CES;
            $scope.CEI.CELT = $scope.selectedCES.CELL;
            if(hasOnlyOne) {
                $scope.itemPR = item2.PR;
                $scope.attendee.PR = item2.PR;
                $scope.CEI.PR = item2.PR;
                $scope.CEI.HR = item2.HR;
                $scope.CEI.UN = item2.UN;
            } else {
                $scope.itemPR = 0;
                $scope.attendee.PR = 0;
            }
        } else {
            $scope.itemPR = item2.PR;
            $scope.attendee.PR = item2.PR;
            $scope.CEI.PR = item2.PR;
            $scope.CEI.HR = item2.HR;
            $scope.CEI.UN = item2.UN;
        }
        $scope.CEI.CES = $scope.selectedCES.CES;
        $scope.CEI.CELT = $scope.selectedCES.CELL;
        $scope.CEI.CETID = item2.CETID;
    }
    $scope.SP.CEI = $scope.CEI;
    $scope.attendee.SP = $scope.SP;
}

// Send handler
$scope.send = function () {
    $scope.attendee.SP = $scope.SP;
    $scope.CEI.CEFN = $scope.CEFN;
    $scope.CEI.CELN = $scope.CELN;
    $scope.CEI.CES = $scope.selectedCES.CES;
    $scope.CEI.CEL = $scope.CELNum;
    $scope.attendee.SP.CEI = $scope.CEI;
    // /Home/SCE
    $("#csubmit").attr('disabled', true);
    $("#cwait").show();
    $http.post("/Home/SCE", JSON.stringify($scope.attendee))
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                var url = "/";
                url += data.controller;
                url += "/";
                url += data.action;
                if(data.link!="") {
                    url+= "/?link="+data.link;
                }
                if(data.msg!="") {
                    url+= "/msg="+data.msg;
                }
                $("#ce_submit").attr('disabled', false);
                $("#ce_wait").hide();
                window.location = url;
        });            
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code related to the controller ? I don't see any <form> element here, is that normal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the initial values for the `select` and `radio` inputs in the controller itself.  E.g.

```
$scope.selectedCES = 'whatever'
```

Note that you'll have to add an `ng-model` to your radio input too.

To validate when the input is required:

```
<select ... required="true">
  ...
</select>

<input ... required="true"/>
```

See the angular docs:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: Is the required attribute the same as HTML5 required attribute ?

Comment: Not quite, different browsers may handle the `required` attribute differently.  What I've shown above is the way the angular docs suggest, so should be implemented consistently in browsers that support angular.

Comment: Yes but I mean : does Angular provide another check than the "normal" HTML5 required attribute (on browsers that support both HTML5 and AngularJS)?

Comment: For now, Angular provides support beyond HTML5.  So for example this validation would still work (in theory) on IE8 if it used `required="true"` and let angular handle it rather than simply using `required` for HTML5.  Note that Angular 1.3 will be breaking legacy browser support though

Comment: I put `ng-required="(item.CTC.length>1)"`on the radio and a required attribute on the state and it works exactly like we expected it should. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code you provide is related to a controller, you could **put a method in your controller scope that checks the inputs / select / radio / whatever before submitting your form**.

```
$scope.isFormValid = function(){
 if($scope.selectedCES.value != "") {
    return true;
 }
 // feel free to put other statements that returns true
 //
 // or
 else {
    return false;
 }
}

$scope.submitForm = function(){
  if($scope.isFormValid()){
    document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
  }
  else {
    console.log("$scope.isFormValid() = false;");
  }
}
```

And on your view :

```
<form id="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
```

*That's not a full answer, but I think that can help you to do it on your project.*

Comment: This is reinventing the validation functionality already provided by angular. It does make sense to duplicate validation logic on the server, but duplicating it on the client isn't needed.

Comment: I understand your point. But what if you need to apply classes on inputs that are not valid (e.g. .error) ?

Comment: Again, that is already provided by angular... https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: Yes, I was reading it too, didn't know about that, really interesting :) Maybe update your answer with this doc ?

Comment: Added. Skimming the docs first and using a framework properly is almost always going to save time

Comment: That's for sure. But I always thought required attribute was exactly the same as required attribute of HTML5, when obviously, it's not quite the same. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like since I don't have a ng-model on the radios that I'm going to have to use a hybrid of both using the required attribute on the select and checking the value of the radios in the send(), do you guys see the same thing?

Comment: You can't put a ng-model on the radio buttons ?